# Hide all product's price for no logged users except for someone

Tags: php, wordpress

I have hidden all product's price until the user isn't logged in. Now i want to show always the price of just someone of my products.

Can anyone help me with the code?

Here's my php code used in function.php :

```
    /**Hide price*/
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('wc_price','members_only_price_pages');
function members_only_price_pages($price){  
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){          
        return $price;      } 
            else {          
                return '<a href="https://www.dentaltechnologiesitalia.it/register/" class="bottone-c">LOGIN PER VEDERE IL PREZZO</a>';      }  }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Unclear if you want to show price to only 1 logged in user?

Comment: @Fresz no, the code is running, but i have to edit it for be able to show always the price of specific products

Comment: @gael no, with this code all of my products have the price hidden, until login. But i have to edit my code for show the price of specific products to all users (though they are not logged)

Comment: You can use `is_page()` to define which products should be ignored and return price. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Would you create a specific category for that?

Comment: @Fresz thank you, but using `is_page()` i can display price on the page of the single product, but not on the shop page right? Because on the shop page i have 20 products, but i want to display only the price of 7 or 8 products

Comment: @gael yes i have a specific category for those products, i have already used `is_product_category` but it works only in the page of that category

Comment: Then you need `has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $post );` https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/if-product-in-category.html

Comment: @Fresz thank you, now with this functions it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is_product_category()` Checks If Current Page is a Product Category.

What you need here is to check if the product belongs to a specific category with the `has_term()` function.

If not user is logged in and the product belongs to category private_cat (for example), the price is replaced:

```
   /**Hide price*/
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price','members_only_price_pages');
add_filter('wc_price','members_only_price_pages');
function members_only_price_pages($price){  
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() && has_term( 'private_cat', 'product_cat' ) ){          
         return '<a href="https://example.com/register/" class="bottone-c">LOGIN PER VEDERE IL PREZZO</a>';
      } 
      else {
         return $price; 
       }
      }
```